# How can I package a Java WS application written in Intellij into something easily executable on Linux?

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea, jar

I created a basic web service in Java by following the steps found here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service-on-glassfish-application-server.html#d76541e339

How can I now package this as a jar or something similar so that I can port it more easily to other systems?

Comment: You can't package a WS app as a JAR file.  (Well ... you can, but it won't help).  You can package it as a WAR or an EAR depending on what you want to deploy it to.

Comment: @StephenC Okay, that makes sense. So if I package it as a WAR, which what got setup by following those steps anyway, can I then just deploy it to something like Tomcat, or is there more to be done to make sure dependencies are correct?

Comment: If the WAR contains all of the dependencies, and you haven't included non-standard stuff in your deployment descriptors, etc, then it may work.  But remember that Tomcat is not a full Java EE container.  Whatever you do, you are going to need to deal with container related issues.  Porting Java EE applications is not as easy as porting Java SE applications.  Generally speaking, people design for one platform, and stick with it.